# count number of inputs which have value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

js noob here - I'm trying to count the number of inputs that have a value out of a calculated number of them. The code I came up with trying to achieve that is the following:

```
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=example-]'), count = 0;
for (var z = 0; z <= fields.length; z++) {
    if (fields[z].value != "") {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    console.log('count is: ' + count);
}
```

Context: there are 3 inputs total and the above code executes on a click event.

Now the first time, this obviously runs fine if for example I set the value of the first input out of the three and returns [1]. The second time I update the **same** field's value, the counter increases again (logically).

Now, what I would like to achieve is to check all three inputs at the time the event fires & count how many of them have a value (and not increase the counter furthermore if they are already counted as having a value in the previous fire event).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: reset your count to 0 when the event is fired. At every event fired the count will start from 0 and output should count how many input fields have a value.

Comment: @J_K simple as that - worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter

```
const count = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=example-]')]
  .filter(fld => fld.value.trim() !== "")
  .length
```

Comment: Holy sh*t, this is even better - it doesn't even throw the value of undefined exception that was halting my code! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is fld? please explain.

Comment: it is the name I give each of the id^=example fields